# Excel diagrams with labels instead of numbers on y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, diagrams

I want an Excel line diagram with text labels instead of numbers on the y-axis (like 'low', 'high', 'higher') and number or date values on the x-axis.

How can I achieve this?

Having a column with the dates and one with the labels doesn't work.

Comment: Not added as an answer as it's a link:  [Chart Axis – Use Text Instead of Numbers](https://www.automateexcel.com/charts/axis-text/)